# Toggle between two loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

As a way to learn more about jQuery, I'm trying to make a function that will scroll to the bottom of the page, back to the top and then start again in an infinite loop.

so far I have got this

```
var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

setInterval(function(){
        scroll += 5;
        $(document).scrollTop(scroll);
}, 10);
```

This will scroll to the bottom of the page.

When it hits the bottom it needs to set a flag, maybe `var direction = 1`
where 1 is down and 0 is up.

Now I need to add something like

```
if(direction){
    // scroll down
} else {
    // scroll up
}
```

So I the IF would constantly check the value of `direction` and increment the `scroll` var by either += 5 or -=5

Does that sound logical or is there a much simpler way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Here is a working version of [somethinghere's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29702757/4801673) suggestion

https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/evkxou3e/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use jQuerys callback to create an infinitely recursing function. Just add a function after the declaration in your animate function, and then call the same function, but invert the passed boolean.

Also, animate will do this incrementing very nice and smoothly for you!

```
function scrollTopOrBottom(top){
    if(top) $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, function(){
        scrollTopOrBottom(false);
    });
    else $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: $("document").height()}, function(){
        scrollTopOrBottom(true);
    });
}

scrollTopOrBottom(false);
```

Update: As mentioned, this could create a * * ahem * * Stack Overflow, but the question is not concerned with that at this point. If you want to be safe, use a `stop()` after each `$("body, html")` statement to stop the call from proceeding if another one is in progress, therefore deferring overflow.

*Note: You could also wrap the `if` statement in `{}` but since it's one statement I find it a bit more legible, more sentence-like than code-like. But thats preference.*

Comment: Of course, animate! Thank you somethinghere, I didn't think setInterval() was going the be the right way to be doing it.

Comment: Please add the brackets for the if/else statements ;)

Comment: @andybeli this way is not incorrect, but I'll mention it. I just think that, when executing just this one statement, I find this more legible... It literally read `if...else`.

Comment: I'd defer the recursive call so there's no threat of a stack overflow.

Comment: It's definitely not incorrect! But it's much more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that the (true) / (false) in the call back functions are the wrong way around and loop the same outcome

Comment: @JoshStevenson Oh sh*t. Will amend that. Woops!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of direction to be either `1` to scroll down or `-1` to scroll up.

Then when changing the value of scroll you can do something like:

```
scroll += 5 * direction;
```